# How to delete an object from a Set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, set

I would appreciate assistance regarding how to remove/delete a specific object from a Set in JavaScript.  I have not been able to find the answer to this seemingly simple question online. 
Please see the following simple example Set:

```
let mySet = new Set([1, 2, {Name: "Ann"}]);

Set(3) {1, 2, {…}}



mySet.delete(1);  

console.log(mySet);

Set(2) {2, {…}}
```

// The basic syntax above doesn't seem to delete an object within a Set. I have tried the following, none of which removed the object:

```
mySet.delete({"Name": "Ann"});
false

mySet.delete("Name");
false

mySet.delete("Ann");
false
```

Is there a different approach that will remove a specific object from a Set in JavaScript?  Perhaps a for...of loop, but then how to specify the specific object for removal? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: You will need a reference to *that specific object*, not a new object with equal values.

Comment: Iterate by Set using eg. `forEach` and find the reference of deleting value. And then delete that reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete

Comment: Thank you Bergi and Ivan for kindly replying and sharing your knowledge.  I appreciate it very much!  :)

Answer (score 8):

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or **object references**.

So this will simply add 2 objects to `Set` since they do not have the **same** object references.

```js
var mySet = new Set([{Name: "Ann"}, {Name: "Ann"}]);

console.log(mySet.size) // 2
```

You might as well use an array in this case.

So in this scenario to remove `Ann` (since we do not have an object reference) we would have to:

```js
var mySet = new Set([1, 2, "abc", {Name: "Ann"}]);

console.log('With Ann size:', mySet.size)

mySet.forEach(x => x.Name === 'Ann' ? mySet.delete(x) : x)

console.log('Bye Ann size:', mySet.size)
```

Now consider this:

```js
var ann = {Name: 'Ann'}
var mySet = new Set([ann, ann])

console.log('With Ann size:', mySet.size)

mySet.delete(ann)

console.log('Bye Ann size:', mySet.size)
```

So as you can see we are now dealing with object references and firstly the size is **only** 1 and the `Set` can now find `ann` **reference** and remove it with no issues.

Comment: Thank you, Akrion.  I am grateful for your guidance.  I like the use of the Set built-in forEach method for iterating through the Set.  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to initialise the object before passing it to `Set`. And retain reference to is (i.e. scope);

```
const person = { name: "Ann" };
const my_set = new Set([1, 2, person]);
my_set.has(person); //true
my_set.delete(person);
my_set.has(person); // false
```

Otherwise;

```
const my_set = new Set([1, 2, { name: "Ann" }]);
my_set.forEach(item => { if (item.name === "Ann") my_set.delete(item); });
```

Comment: Hello Mudlabs, thanks for your solutions.  As I expressed also to Akrion, the use of the Set's built-in forEach method makes a lot of sense to me now.  But I also see great value in initializing the object before passing it to the Set, when possible.  In that scenario, it seems to be even more straightforward.  Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is,

1. Convert the Set into an Array
2. Filter the object out of there using a stringified comparison*
3. Convert the Array back into a Set

* Careful since this considers order of keys.

You can use this function:

```
function removeObjectFromSet (set, obj) {
    return new Set([...set].filter((el) => JSON.stringify(el) != JSON.stringify(obj)))
}
```

For example, like this:

```
let mySet = new Set([1, 2, { Name: "Ann" }])

mySet = removeObjectFromSet(mySet, { Name: "Ann" })
console.log(mySet)
```

Comment: Hi Naranjja, thank you so much for kindly replying and sharing your solution.  I love that all of the Array methods are available for use after converting the Set to an Array and back to a Set afterwards.  Having received various solutions, I realize it's important to be able understand each of the provided solutions and yet I'm curious as to which of the recommended approaches above performs the task most efficiently.  Thank you so much!  :)